# Windows batch to search for keyword in a file and apply condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch to look for a keyword such as "Failed" "Error" in a log file and apply condition to write it in another file.

Ex: a.) abc.log ...
search.bat - if abc.log has a word such as "Error" or "Failed", ECHO "DATA LOAD FAILED" Else ECHO "DATA LOAD SUCCESS"

Tried this,

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /c:"EPMAT" C:\Temp_logs\ExpDataload.log') do set ErrorCount=%%a

IF  /I "%ErrorCount%" == "EPMAT-1:Command Failed to execute." (
    SET Message="DATA LOAD FAILED"
) ELSE (
    SET Message="DATA LOAD SUCCESS"
)

ECHO %Message%
```

But, %ErrorCount% is storing the entire line, instead of keyword. So I even tried to check the entire line, still it always shows "DATA LOAD SUCCESS" instead of FAILED.

I might be missing something in the IF Condition.

Comment: Did you tag PowerShell here because you're open to using a PowerShell script?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking only for a windows batch solution right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findstr` outputs the matching lines it finds. Your loop assigns, consecutively, each line of this output to `ErrorCount`.

So, after the loop, the variable will hold the *last* match found, which may be your problem, if you maybe try to compare to the first match.

But, if no match was found, the variable will actually be empty, so you can just compare to `""`:

```
IF  /I "%ErrorCount%" == "" (
    SET Message="DATA LOAD SUCCESS"
) ELSE (
    SET Message="DATA LOAD FAILED"
)
```

Alternatively, if you're not really interested in the actual line found, just check the errorlevel like in @TessellatingHeckler's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a test that script form works for me. And yes, ErrorCount will become the whole line - I can only guess there is some mismatched spaces where the strings aren't equal. Can you post some lines from ExpDataload.log ?

As an alternate approach, findstr can search for multiple words, and sets a return/errorlevel of 0 if it finds a match or 1 if it fails:

```
findstr /I "failed error" c:\temp_logs\expdataload.log 
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo "DATA LOAD FAILED"
) else (
    echo "DATA LOAD SUCCESS"
)
```

Edit with @aschipfl's change to make it ... work. :-|

Comment: Sorry this dint work, its showing up "DATA LOAD SUCCESS" even after finding errors.

Comment: I think I might have just reversed the logic and broken it. Try this edited version.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, `if ErrorLevel 0` checks if `ErrorLevel` is *`0` or greater*! you need to replace it by `if not ErrorLevel 1`.

Comment: Thanks TessellatingHeckler. It works. I have one more question. How do I mention a condition for two keywords, such as "Error" and "FAILED". If it finds either of those, it should echo "DATA LOAD FAILED" else "DATA LOAD SUCCESS".

Comment: @cec4111 I think it already does that, the test in findstr matches either word, doesn't it?